# Creating CORS rules for AWS S3 via PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This has been driving me crazy for several days, and I know that I'm missing something simple. I've been attempting to update CORS for a bucket that I create on the fly using the PHP SDK.

This is what I've attempted to hack together out of the various tutorials that I've found: (one thing I'm not sure about is the prefered method of sending multiple AllowedMethods).

```
    $result = $s3Client->putBucketCors(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'CORSConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'AllowedOrigins' => array('AllowedOrigin' => '*'),
            'AllowedMethods' => array('AllowedMethods' => 'POST'),
            'AllowedMethods' => array('AllowedMethods' => 'GET'),
            'AllowedMethods' => array('AllowedMethods' => 'PUT'),
        'MaxAgeSeconds' => array('MaxAgeSeconds' => '3000'),
        'AllowedHeader' => array('AllowedHeader' => '*')
        )
    )
));
```

The above returns the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutBucketCors operation: [CORSConfiguration] must be an associative array.

I've tried to use the information from this page to help, but I know it is out of date: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketCors

I've verified that the bucket exists and is created, through the AWS console. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I was able to pull my CORS off of an existing bucket, and this is what it gave me. Still trying to figure out how to set up my arrays to create:

```
 data:Aws\Result:private] => Array ( 

[CORSRules] => Array ( [0] =>


 Array ( [AllowedHeaders] => Array ( [0] => * )

 [AllowedMethods] => Array ( [0] => GET [1] => POST [2] => PUT )
 [AllowedOrigins] => Array ( [0] => * )[
 MaxAgeSeconds] => 3000 ))
```

Comment: In docs which you shared it says `CORSRules` not `CORSConfiguration` did you aware ? Or something because the doc is not up to date ?

Comment: I noticed it was different in the documentation. I couldn't find a working example for the PHP SDK for the latest version. I used CORSConfiguration because it kept throwing errors at me when I tried CORSRules: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutBucketCors operation: [CORSConfiguration] is missing and is a required parameter'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up figuring this out after a fair amount of trial and error. I went ahead and set the CORSRules as a seperate array, just to make the code a bit more readable. Here's what I came up with, posting in case anyone's in the same boat as me down the line:

```
    $cors = array(array(
        'AllowedOrigins' => array('*'),
        'AllowedMethods' => array('POST', 'GET', 'PUT'),
        'MaxAgeSeconds' => 3000,
        'AllowedHeaders' => array('*')
    ));

   $result = $s3Client->putBucketCors(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'CORSConfiguration' => array('CORSRules' => $cors)
    ));
```

Reading from the doc shared by Feyyaz ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETcors.html ), CORSConfiguration acts as a container, with CORSRules being the associative key inside.

I hope this helps anyone who finds themselves in the same boat I was in.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $result = $s3Client->putBucketCors(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'CORSRules' => array(
        array(
            'AllowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'AllowedMethods' => array('POST', 'GET', 'PUT'),
            'MaxAgeSeconds' => 3000,
            'AllowedHeaders' => array('*')
        )
    )
));
```

It may work could you please try it ?
You have multiple AllowedMethods, it doesn't make any sense the last one just overrides the previous two of them.

Also in doc you shared it says `CORSRules` but `CORSConfigurations` coming from response this doc says http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETcors.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I attempted the above, and got this result:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutBucketCors operation: [CORSConfiguration] is missing and is a required parameter'.

Replacing CORSRules with CORSConfigurations gives me the original error message I posted: [CORSConfiguration] must be an associative array. 
I assume it's because the documentation is for an older version, so I'm just trying to figure out which changes to make for it to work now. Thank you again.